What do you call a biased mediator?
My client was the owner of the land and the shrubs that grew from it, but the branches encroached onto his land she decided to take them all down to stop any further unpleasantries. Where  upon the neighbour asked his friend (another Ex-councillor) to mediate  unbiased.
The mediator expressed several back handed threats of, "If you take away all of the shrubs away he could plant trees of 30ft on his side and you couldn't do a thing about it" " There might be tree preservation orders on the hedge" and so on.
He was clearly pretending to mediate but was actually intimidating in a back handed way. What is the name given to a bulling prick like him. I saw agent provocateur but does this fit?

For best results, please give a sample sentence showing how the word would fit in. Personally, I suspect you'll get more mileage on this concept with verbs and adjectives than with a noun (bullying, intimidation, duplicity, evasiveness—ok, those are actually all nouns, but describing actions rather than the actor). Plus it's generally a good idea in disputes, especially when angry, so that you can't be accused of name-calling and rather are focusing on what the other person did and why it matters.

The simple accomplice could work.

It's not very clear who 'his' is, and other parties involved, or why the neighbour needs a mediator when 'she' has taken down her own branches. It comes over as a rant, with 'bulling prick'.

You could consider the word shill.  Per OED, the term came into use in the early 20th century, meaning:

A decoy or accomplice, esp. one posing as an enthusiastic or successful customer to encourage other buyers, gamblers, etc.

Early uses refer to shills working for casinos, carnival shows and the like.  Over time, it seems to have been used less with reference to legitimate enterprises and more with confidence games.
The "additional" sense in the OED is not attested until 1976 and is more pertinent to your request:

transferred. One who poses as a disinterested advocate of another but is actually of the latter's party; a mouthpiece, a stooge. [emphasis mine]

Here is an example use from 1983 in The Chicago Sun Times:

Observer? Baloney. Will was no observer. Breslin calls Will a ‘shill’ for the president and he is exactly right.


Chicago Sun-Times 12 July 7


They could be called

partisan
strongly supporting a person, principle, or political party, often without considering or judging the matter very carefully

From Cambridge Dictionary.
